# Is it possible to make this page an offline web app to the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, web-applications, offline

www.mark??z.se/test
Remove the: ??

It is only 4 files:

index.html
appIcon.png
startup.PNG
SMS_2.jpg

How can i make this to an offline app, is it possible?

The CSS and all JS are in the html file.

Answer (score 2):

Read about creating offline web apps here:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

The iPhone Safari browser supports offline web apps.  You need to:

- modify the webpage to reference a cache.manifest file
- create a cache.manifest file listing the resources that need to be downloaded
- configure your web server to serve the cache.manifest file with the proper content type

I used this reference (among others) to create an offline GWT web app.  iPhone/Safari can "bookmark" the website by using "Add to Home Screen" so it looks like an iphone native app.

Good luck.

Comment: "configure your web server to serve the cache.manifest file with the proper content type"  How do i do that, beacause i downloaded a demo on a offline page and put all the files on my host but its still don't want to work. What do i do?

Comment: @user558773 - its server-specific.  For example, http://diveintohtml5.org/offline.html#manifest says "If you are running an Apache-based web server, you can probably just put an AddType directive in the .htaccess file at the root of your web directory. ... If you use a different web server or a different configuration of Apache, consult your server’s documentation on controlling the Content-Type header."

Comment: diveintohtml5 URL has changed (been mirrored) to diveintohtml5.ep.io

Answer (score 0):

The UIWebView
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html
is capable of displaying html content that has javascript and css associated with it.  I should be possible to include your files as part of the app's bundle and have the UIWebView load them.  Have a read through that class reference and sample code to see if it suits your needs.

Comment: So what do i need to do? Is it a prgram or somthing that can do it? Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

in  a desktop pc, be shure every resource is boundled with the html file, css inlines, js inlines, images encoded in css via  url('data:image')
@see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
and associate a browser to html files, doubleclick on the page will open your page.
also chrome has a "create application shortcut" that will make an even more "native" frame around your html5 app.
prism https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism is the same concept implemented with mozilla engine.

in mobile browsers based on webkit there are similar means to exploit, i.e. for iPad you can create shortcuts in the home screen that will look exactly like a native application and access a 5Mb of file cache(http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

Comment: CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
appIcon.PNG